vectors hit points without raycasting
I am recording eye movements data in virtual reality using Varjo Aero HMD. Based on the data I'm collecting, i'm struggling to get the gaze hit point in the world space without raycasting. Here is what I have so far that helps me to (I believe) have the gaze direction in world space but as the vector is normalized, I can't get exactly the point in my environment where the collision occurs with my target.
How would I have to proceed to compute the hit point, if - for example - I know the distance between the origin and the target ? Would multiplying the normalized vector by the distance suffice, as shown below ? This seems like a very trivial question but doing this, I can't find the same results as when using a raycast hit
using UnityEngine;

public class GazeTracking : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector3 HMDPosition; // Camera.transform.localPosition
    public Quaternion HMDRotation; // Camera.transform.localRotation
    public Vector3 GazePosition; // origin (x, y, z), relative to HMD
    public Vector3 GazeDirection; // normalized direction vector forward (x, y, z) relative to HMD
    public float magnitude = 20f;

    void Update()
    {
        // Gaze Position to World Space
        Vector3 worldGazePosition = HMDPosition + GazePosition;

        // Gaze Direction from Local to World 
        Vector3 worldGazeDirection = HMDRotation * GazeDirection;

        Vector3 denormalizedVector = magnitude * worldGazeDirection;

        // Compute Gaze hit point
        Vector3 gazeHitPoint = worldGazePosition + denormalizedVector ;
    }
}

EDIT
I tried computing the hitpoint with a raycast or by calculating it myself and there is still something I can't figure out :
Vector3 GazeDirection is different from one frame to the next but when I convert it to world space, two different GazeDirection can obtain the same values in world coordinates even if HMDPosition, HMDRotation and GazePosition are constant. This doesn't look right, I must be missing something.


You can probably not just add the HMDPosition and GazePosition, since the worldPosition also depend on the HMD rotation. You normally create a matrix/transform to translate between different coordinate spaces. Do note that Unity uses different methods depending if a vector represents a point or direction. Also, if you just want a point at some distance along a ray, you may want to avoid terms like "hit point", since I assume that means the intersection point between the ray and something else.

Thanks for the answer !
Do you mean that converting between local to world is not as straightforward as translating origin and transforming position ?
I'd better then just use something like this ?
origin = Camera.transform.TransformPoint(GazePosition)
direction = Camera.transform.TransformDirection(GazeDirection)
fixationPoint (and not hit point ;)) = origin + direction * distance

Yes something like that. You might need to invert the transforms depending on how they are defined and in what direction you need to convert stuff. Just note that transforms are notoriously easy to get wrong. Unit testing, debug tools & visualizations may help.

You btw also get the focus distance from Varjo: https://developer.varjo.com/docs/unity-xr-sdk/eye-tracking-with-varjo-xr-plugin float focusDistance - The distance between eye and focus point in meters. Values are between 0 and 2 meters.

If this ray actually hits an object - you either have to calculate yourself or use Raycasting ;)

I updated my post to clarify where the problem lies with data as an example ! Thanks for your clarifications
